# Good practice: Pagination links in html lists?

Tags: html, css, web, pagination

Do we put pagination links in html lists like for instance we do it with navigation links?

Comment: yes, there are many ways to do it - if you don't mind using javascript, then try some of these jquery examples - http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pagination

Comment: also, here are a few non-javascript approaches http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/03/perfect-pagination-style-using-css.html - it all depends on your development infrastructure though

Answer (score 2):

Anything that's a list should be marked up as a list — including a list of navigation links for pagination.

Comment: Just to play devils advocate, I'd like to hear a little more insight. Is a set of numbered page links really a list? If so, is it a `ul` or `ol`. Although I agree with the semantics of an `ol`, the rendered HTML does look a little funny as 1. 1, 2. 2, etc.

Comment: Well, the **rendered** HTML obviously depends entirely on the CSS rules applied. I agree that the default rendering would be a bit silly, though; this is a case where I'd probably favor a `ul` for that reason — especially since some of the list elements are likely things like "First" and "Next" which are not really part of the ordered sequence.